# How to check if email was delivered using C# MailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-mail

I am using below code to send email it works fine most of the time & during test we found sometimes it doesn't deliver email. How can i alter this code to check the email delivery status or font any other failure.

```
        public static void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string message, bool isHtml)
        {
            try
            {
            var mail = new MailMessage();

            // Set the to and from addresses.
            // The from address must be your GMail account
            mail.From = new MailAddress("noreplyXYZ@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

            // Define the message
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
            mail.Body = message;

            // Create a new Smpt Client using Google's servers
            var mailclient = new SmtpClient();
            mailclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";//ForGmail
            mailclient.Port = 587; //ForGmail


            // This is the critical part, you must enable SSL
            mailclient.EnableSsl = true;//ForGmail
            //mailclient.EnableSsl = false;
            mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            // Specify your authentication details
            mailclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreplyXYZ@gmail.com", "xxxx123");//ForGmail
            mailclient.Send(mail);
            mailclient.Dispose();
    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
    throw ex;
                        }
    }
```

I know SMTP is responsible for sending email & it is not possible to delivery status but is their a way around to check the status of the email delivery

**UPDATED CODE** (is this correct)

```
public static void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string message, bool isHtml)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();

    // Set the to and from addresses.
    // The from address must be your GMail account
    mail.From = new MailAddress("noreplyXYZ@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

    // Define the message
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
    mail.Body = message;

    // Create a new Smpt Client using Google's servers
    var mailclient = new SmtpClient();
    mailclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";//ForGmail
    mailclient.Port = 587; //ForGmail

    mailclient.EnableSsl = true;//ForGmail
    //mailclient.EnableSsl = false;
    mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    // Specify your authentication details
    mailclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreplyXYZ@gmail.com", "xxxx123");//ForGmail
    mailclient.Send(mail);
    mailclient.Dispose();
    try
    {
        mailclient.Send(mail);
        mailclient.Dispose();
    }
    catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
        {
            SmtpStatusCode status = ex.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
            if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("Delivery failed - retrying in 5 seconds.");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                mailclient.Send(mail);
            }
            else
            {
                //  Console.WriteLine("Failed to deliver message to {0}", ex.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //  Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}",ex.ToString());
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        mailclient.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you have the entire body of code wrapped in a `try` block with an empty `catch` block. So, if the message fails to send for whatever reason, you will have **no idea** because your function will simply return.

If you look at the MSDN documentation for [`SmtpClient.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) you'll see that there are a number of different exceptions it can throw for various reasons. A couple interesting ones:

- [`SmtpException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception.aspx)
- [`SmtpFailedRecipientsException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception.aspx)

---

A couple of notes after your update:

You probably don't mean to do this:

```
mailclient.Send(mail);
mailclient.Dispose();
try
{
    mailclient.Send(mail);
    mailclient.Dispose();
}
```

You're disposing `mailclient` before trying to use it again.

### `using`

`MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` both implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), so it would be best practice (and easiest) to put them in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block:

```
using (var mail = new MailMessage())
using (var mailclient = new SmtpClient())
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you won't have to worry about calling `Dispose()` in your `finally` blocks (you may not need them at all then).

### `throw`

You're probably aware, but there's no point in:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex; 
}
```

### `foreach`

```
for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
{
    SmtpStatusCode status = ex.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
    // ... 
}
```

Can be re-written as:

```
foreach (var innerEx in ex.InnerExceptions)
{
    var status = innerEx.StatusCode;
}
```

### `Thread.Sleep()`

If this code is user-facing, you probably don't really want to do this, as it is going to cause the page to hang for 5 seconds waiting to send.  In my opinion, you shouldn't handle sending mail directly in the web page code anyway, you should queue it up for a background task to send. But that's an entirely different issue.

Just a few things to help make you a better C# coder.

Comment: Agree, this is partial code problem is that when even email is not delivered it still wont raise any exception

Comment: Right, but provided everything goes through with the SMTP transaction, I'm not sure that there *is* any way for you to know. Just like when you send an email with your mail client. The only way you can know that delivery failed (after it hopped its way across the internet) is that you get a "delivery failed" reply email, usually from their ISP/mail provider

Comment: Do you also check for error in the OnSendCompleted method? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.onsendcompleted

Comment: @Misha that's only raised if you call [`SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecwxwx34), not if you use the regular (synchronous) `Send` methods. With the sync methods, the same exception would be raised directly.

Comment: @Jonathon, I have updated code in the question. Please see if that can help me to trap all error and delivery failure also which is important

Comment: `mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` set it to `false`.. you are providing your credentials

Comment: @Niranjan, You are right brother i have made code changes to my actual code.. I am not sure how i missed that one. Thanks

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ah sorry I missed / misread that part.

Answer (score 1):

> It sounds like you're asking if there's a way in real time to check to
>   see if your user got the message. If so, I would recommend that you
>   don't pursue that path. While most times email delivery seems to be
>   instantaneous, it could be held up for any length of time prior to
>   being delivered to the recipient's mailbox.

I suggest you to go through following asp.net forum links:
[SMTP server and email FAQ](http://forums.asp.net/p/1189023/2038523.aspx)
[Delivery Notification Not Working when Sending Emails](http://forums.asp.net/t/1111538.aspx)
[Best Practice to do implement checking if the email sent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3300366/770710)

**Note:** [There is no reliable way to find out if a message was indeed delivered.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4973775/770710)

There are another SO thread already availalbe that you have asked:
[How to check MailMessage was delivered in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973725/how-to-check-mailmessage-was-delivered-in-net)
[ASP.NET MVC How to determine if the e-mail didn't reach the receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300307/asp-net-mvc-how-to-determine-if-the-e-mail-didnt-reach-the-receiver)

Comment: Is there a way we can check the recipient email address is valid one i mean is it associate with the email server for example IamOnGmail@gmail.com / IamNotOnGmail@gmail.com

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873118/checking-if-an-email-address-exists) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1500197.aspx/1) -- [link](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/)